# Display 2 contents types fields in 1 view

Tags: 7, views

I am trying out Drupal 7 - and am a complete noob, so please bear with me!

I have a content type - 'film' which displays various fields about a film and another called 'venue' which displays data about a screening of a film.

I wanted to merge the display of content types film and venue so that they display in the same screen (all the fields in one screen). Is this possible? Do I do it with views? I have heard of relations, but I'm finding it all confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a 'venue' content type linked through a node reference field, you can do it using a relation in a view.

Comment: I have done that, but all I seem to get is a link to the node and not the actual fields within that node. Is there a way to get the fields and not just the link?

Comment: It's possible if you create a field that réference the node id of the venue.
Check this link out: http://drupal.org/node/289738

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfect sample for views attach. If anyone is still waiting or looking for a solution: http://drupal.org/project/eva

Answer (score 0):

by using entity reference make a call to particular node.and in views you can add the relations based on reference.then you can display the both in single page

eg: In venue type-create node and give reference of film.in views relations display based on the reference field